# Build complex result table with dynamic columns

Tags: mysql

I have a question - trying to find a solution here, but that what I see is not as my situation. So:

In TABLE1 we have some article descriptions

```
ID  | Name
1   | Doors
2   | Chairs
```

In TABLE2 we have a article properties

```
ID  |ID_article | Descr
1   |1          | Type
2   |1          | Material
3   |2          | Height
4   |2          | Width
5   |2          | Toll
```

In TABLE3 we have a article list with properties values like

```
Article | ID_art_descr | ID_art_prop | Value
Model1  | 1            | 1           | Solid
Model1  | 1            | 2           | Wood
Model2  | 1            | 1           | Solid
Model2  | 1            | 2           | Steel
```

The goal is to build a table, which list article from given group with properties for that group. for example, for doors, the table must have columns:

```
Article | Type  | Material
Model1  | Solid | Wood
Model2  | Solid | Steel
```

For Chairs, the table must have other columns:

```
Article | Height | Width | Toll
........
```

So for every article group, the columns count and lables will be different. I was write script on aspx and php which do this, but that method have difficults with sorting or filtering the result table (in some case, we have more than 10k ot rows). So I wonder is there a way to generate a result table on MySQL?

And here is the sqlfiddle description for Table1, Table2 and Table3:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53e32/1

Thank you strawberry

Comment: This is starting to look like an EAV. Is it? Nothing wrong with that. Just, I tend to avoid them like the plague.

Comment: Just build a simple, ordered result, and handle the data display at the application level - e,g. with a bit of PHP.

Comment: Yes, there are some of EAV methods here... But this is only the part of bigger project. That i mentioned above is part where data is imported from out source. At now, after handle all properties, i generate a new database with fixed structure based on given variant... My problem is that the project is grow now and all that income stream is need more control... that is why i need some abbility like sorting and filtering... so thank you anyway, i'll try to refine my php/asp code!

Comment: Have you considered other db options like MongoDB?

Comment: @JoeFrambach - yes, we did already try mongoDB for our task. Maybe in near future... We have a lot of mathematical procedures that perform after that problem that I describe... I say, mongoDB is great possibility... thank you.